# A simple Geometry Doubt

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles

In the figure below there are two congruent squares, then what fraction of larger circle area is the green circle area?

[image]

Basically i assumed that the points of tangencies of green circle and the centre of larger circle are collinear and got the fraction as $\frac{1}{10}$. But how to prove that they are collinear? For give me if its a silly doubt.

Comment: The side of the square that is a chord of the circle gets divided in two by the radius that is perpendicular to it. That radius, since it is perpendicular to that side, must be parallel to the two "horizontal" sides of the same square. Therefore, this radius also passes through the mid point of the other vertical side of the square.

Comment: Oh yeah Perp bisector of a chord always passes through the center. Thanks now its clear.

Comment: One way to get the proportion can be the following. Look at the $3$ vertices of the squares that are on the big circle. If $s$ is the side of the squares, then the are of that triangle is $\frac{s^2}{2}$. But the are of a triangle is equal to $\frac{abc}{4R}$, where $R$ is the radius of the circumscribed circle. The sides of that triangle are $s,s\sqrt{2},s\sqrt{5}$, by Pythagoras. So, we get $\frac{s^2}{2}=\frac{s^3\sqrt{10}}{4R}$.  If the radius of the little circle is $r$, then $2r=s$. So, we get $\frac{r}{R}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "traditional" approach:

The large circle is the circumcircle of a triangle whose sides are in the proportion $1 : \sqrt{2} : \sqrt{5}$, thus if this triangle is denoted by $\triangle ABC$, the circumradius is $$R = \frac{abc}{4|\triangle ABC|} = \frac{\sqrt{10}}{4(1/2)} = \frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$$ if we take the side length of the square--and hence the green incircle's diameter--to be unity.  Thus the ratio of the smaller circle's area to the larger is simply $\frac{r^2}{R^2} = \frac{1}{10}.$

---

A "tricky" approach:

Exploit symmetry of the diagram.  Mirror the bottom square across the common diameter through both circles, and then mirror the resulting three squares across the perpendicular diameter of the large circle.  Finally, fill in the three squares in the center column to make a $3 \times 3$ array of squares, as shown in the following diagram:
[image]
Now it is plainly obvious that the large circle satisfies $$R^2 = (\tfrac{3}{2} s)^2 + (\tfrac{1}{2} s)^2 = \frac{5}{2} s^2,$$ where $s$ is the side length of the square; and the small circle satisfies $r^2 = (s/2)^2 = s^2/4$, so again $$\frac{r^2}{R^2} = \frac{1/4}{5/2} = \frac{1}{10}.$$

If it is not clear why the figure should obey such symmetry, consider that the common diameter through both circles is an axis of symmetry for the square that contains the green circle.  So the square that is drawn below it, when reflected about this axis, must also intersect with the upper arc of the large circle in the same way as it does with the lower.  We can justify the claim that the center column of squares are also congruent because the "corner" squares have a *diagonal* axis of symmetry with the large circle, since their opposite vertices are points of intersection with the circle.

Comment: Very interesting...can see the hard work put up to create this beautiful figure

Comment: Hm, how do you know "Finally, fill in the three **squares** in the center column"? I can only conclude that they are rectangles, how do you tell that the width is equal to the height?  $quad$ Edit: I see further explanations in the last paragraph. Let me think this through.

Comment: @CalvinLin A circle that passes through the opposite vertices of any square must have its center on the line passing through the diagonal of the other two vertices.  By reflecting about this diagonal, the figure is completed as claimed.

Comment: That's a good justification. Thanks. (+1 already)